# Get the id of the link and pass it to the jQueryUI dialog widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using the dialog widget of jQueryUI. Now, the links are grabbed from an SQL database by using jQuery+AJAX which is the reason why I used "live"

```
$(function() {
    var $dialog = $('#report')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 410,
                width: 350,
                draggable: true
            })
        //store reference to placeholders
        $uid = $('#reportUniqueId');

    $('.reportopen').live("click", function (e) {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        var $uid = $(this).attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My question is, how do I pass the `id` of the link that triggered the dialog widget to the dialog box itself? The link is set up like this:

```
<td align="left" width="12%">
  <span id="notes">
    [<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="reportopen" id="<?=$reportId;?>">Spam</a>]
  </span>
</td>
```

And the dialogbox is set up like this:

```
<div id="report" title="Inquire now">
HAHAHAHAHA
<span id="reportUniqueId"></span>
</div>
```

I'd like for the `id` to be passed and generated in the `<span id="reportUniqueId"></span>` part of the dialog box.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".reportopen").click(function(){
var monId= $(this).attr("id");
$("#reportUniqueId").text(monId);
$dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Any idea how come if I use `$("#reportUniqueId").attr('title',monId);` to change the title of the dialogbox, it works but the title doesn't show? Although checking in Firebug, the title was changed in the source code.

Comment: you add this line before or after : $dialog.dialog('open'); ?

Comment: I've tried before and after, it works in changing the title in the source code but it doesn't show on the dialog box per se. Is there a way I can call the variable monId in the .dialog options? Because adding `title: "some title"` there works in changing the dialogbox.

Comment: Can you paste your code right here? Not sure what I'm doing wrong this time.

Comment: $("#report").dialog({
           width:'50%',
        title: monId
       });

Answer (score 0):

When you use the jQuery `click` handler, it passes an  `event` to the function, which you named as `e` in your parameter.

You can inspect this object if you'd like using `console.log`, but the important thing is that `e.target` refers to the DOM element which triggered the click event.
I am sure that you could use jQuery to convert it a wrapped set/element first, i.e.:

```
$(e.target)
```

then you could get its ID using the techniques in the other comments, namely:

```
$(e.target).attr('id')
```

Please let me know if this works.